# Определение типа предложения по структуре

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор, бсп

> Человек уединяется, чтобы поплакать, но изначально он не одинок: когда человек плачет, он просто не хочет, чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам.

Схема: `[... ], (чтобы...), но[...]: (когда...), [... ], (чтобы...)`.

Обозначила как многочленное предложение с разными видами связи (контаминированной структуры). В первой части сочинительная связь, во второй - подчинительная.

Верно?

Comment: _В первой части сочинительная связь_ === И подчинительная тоже есть:  {[... ], (**чтобы**...)}

Comment: _В первой части... во второй..._ === Наверное, надо указать, как эти  части связаны между собой?

Comment: нужно указать отношения между этими частями.
я бы предположила, что пояснительные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно.

/[... ], (чтобы...), но[...]/: /(когда...), [... ], (чтобы...)/.

Многочленное предложение с комбинацией сочинения, подчинения и бессоюзной связи.

1 уровень членения:два структурных компонента связаны бессоюзной связью с пояснительными отношениями.1-двучленное сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным цели  связано с простым двусоставным предложением противительными отношениями;2- трёхчленное сложноподч. предл. с 2 придаточными(времени и изъяснительн.), объединёнными параллельной связью

Comment: а по краям схемы - /
это обязательно?что это означает?

Comment: Нет, это я для Вас заострила две части. Если бы просто в тетради вручную, можно было вместо черт обвести обе конструкции прямоугольником, так обычно делают, а как выделить здесь - не знаю